# Tag synonym request: [keyboard-shortcut] and [key-binding] → [keyboard]

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

The wiki for [keyboard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) says it already covers what [keyboard-shortcut](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcut) and [key-binding](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/key-binding) cover, so I think they should be made synonyms of [keyboard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard).

- [keyboard-shortcut](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcut) → [keyboard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard)
- [key-binding](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/key-binding) → [keyboard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard)

Comment: Probably no sense in forcing `keyboard` to be regarding hardware or other non-controls-aspects.  +1

Answer (score 4):

I'd rather see [keyboard-shortcut](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcut) merged into [key-binding](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/key-binding) or the other way around. The tag [keyboard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) doesn't make much sense to me. Either of the other two is more descriptive.